# Insert Array to another Array then pass to PHP

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following code:

```
d = (d == '') ? 0 : d;
m = (m == '') ? 0 : m;
s = (s == '') ? 0 : s;

dmsArray = new Array(d, m, s);
surveyBearing = new Array();
surveyBearing.push(dir1);
surveyBearing.push(dmsArray);
surveyBearing.push(dir2);

surveyBearings.push(surveyBearing);

dmsArray.length = 0;
```

I have not included the entirety but I will explain it in detail. The variables (d, m, s, dir1, dir2) are taken from the input form. surveyBearing is an array that will be pushed into the surveyBearings array. However, console.log(surveyBearings) shows:

```
[["S", [], "E"], ["S", [], "W"], ["N", [], "W"], ["N", [], "E"]]
```

Am I missing something here? I am sure that dmsArray is not empty because console.log(dmsArray) returns

```
["9", 0, 0]
```

On the PHP side, it returns

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => S
        [1] => Array
            (
            )

        [2] => E
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => S
        [1] => Array
            (
            )

        [2] => W
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => N
        [1] => Array
            (
            )

        [2] => W
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => N
        [1] => Array
            (
            )

        [2] => E
    )

)
```

Comment: well this doesn't make sense, here's something similar to your code and it's working http://jsfiddle.net/bUnbE/
there must be something else!

Comment: I really don't know how to explain this but this worked:

    surveyBearing[1] = new Array();
    surveyBearing[1][0] = d;
    surveyBearing[1][1] = m;
    surveyBearing[1][2] = s;

Using

    surveyBearing.push(dmsArray);

didn't work. It seems that pushing an array to an array without initializing it doesn't work.

If any one has further explanation, please do share it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your var declaration to check `undefined` state too like this:

```
d = (d == '' || typeof d === 'undefined') ? 0 : d;
m = (m == '' || typeof m === 'undefined') ? 0 : m;
s = (s == '' || typeof s === 'undefined') ? 0 : s;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j24k/)

Comment: Great! One step further for me. However console.log(surveyBearings) still returns [["S", [], "E"], ["S", [], "W"], ["N", [], "W"], ["N", [], "E"]]

On the PHP side, it is the same on the question above.